# Android - Splash screen Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, splash-screen

I am currently developing an application with splash screen without action bar, with custom background etc. (so its in full screen mode). However, before splash screen appears there is a "flash" (about 0.5sec long) of white layout with action bar showed. Can somebody explain me how to remove this behavior ? 
Thanks

SplashScreen activity looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    font = new CustomFont(getBaseContext());
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    // Hide an action bar
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    else{
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    //Use custom font
    font.setTypeface((TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashScreenTVTitle));

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer.
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Update your question title properly...

Comment: Show your manifest file. You should not have a Theme defined for your SplashScreenActivity.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I've edited my post (added manifest)

Comment: From your question title, I understand that your application **is** a Splash Screen. Not that it **has** one.

Comment: I had another title, however @PankajKumar has voted down for previous one, and suggested to change it to current one.

Comment: @Creck How did you know that I voted down your question? And does you question title sounds your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an activity as fullscreen within the manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do this to `SplashActivity` and your problem goes away. And remove the getActionBar().hide requests.

Comment: After using what you posted, getting this exception :/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Answer (score 0):

Avoid splash screens.

One of the design patterns of android is "CONTENT FIRST".

Use intermeditate loading bars to give information to end-users.

Comment: Well, it does not look like it's problem of splash screen (as splash screen is an activity like any else), however still cannot get rid of that white layout before app launches :/

Comment: I will add there loading data from DB, which then shows in main activity

Comment: Your main activity should not be called by another activity. Its a design issue for android.

To avoid white layouts you should set your background from theme.
You may research about creating style and background within it.

Comment: Well, that background works, however, ActionBar is still there, and I am unable to disable it with <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> as it requires minimum api11

Comment: You can use AsyncTask to load data without locking UI.

You should still able to move around with UI.

Comment: There should be theme attribute in your "ACTIVITY TAG" in MANIFEST.

theme="@android.Theme.Light.Fullscreen" or something like that.

Comment: There are use cases for Splash Screens. If you have to load your resources BEFORE showing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by defining custom theme and removing part of code that hides action bar within onCreate method.

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```